# deny access to files inside a hidden folder and temporary folders with apache .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess

i have a lot of temporary and hidden folders and files in my site that i want to deny access to all files inside that folders ,
i succeeded to block all the temporary and hidden files/directory with this   htaccess part :

```
<FilesMatch "^\.">
    Order allow,deny
    Deny from all
</FilesMatch>

<FilesMatch "\~$">
    Order allow,deny
    Deny from all
</FilesMatch>
```

it blocks all files and directory beginning with a dot or ending with ~ and that's great but my problem is with folders when i have a folder called "test~" and inside that folder i have a file that don't matches with \~$ or ^. this url **"mysite.tld/.test/file.ext** will be not forbidden

Comment: So you want to block `mysite.tld/test~/file.ext` as well?

Comment: yes exactly i want to block the files inside blocked folders that dont end with ~ or . that's it

Comment: Did Jon's answer work for you?

Comment: Note that you could also write theses things *outside* of the DocumentRoot, so you would'nt have to restrict access on it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try adding:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule (^|/)\.([^/]+)(/|$) - [L,F]
RewriteRule (^|/)([^/]+)~(/|$) - [L,F]
```